# Insert Android Preferences-like inside another Activity and layout

Tags: android, layout, android-preferences, sharedpreferences

I'm designing an application that searches a bunch of items and I was wondering if there was a way to place a Preferences-like layout (similar to Shared Preferences) inside a SlidingDrawer, for example, so I could filter the results. I don't mind whether it actually uses the Shared Preferences system or not (and I don't find it possible at all), though it would be a plus. So, as mentioned:

**Is there a way to insert a Preference layout inside another layout?**

I include my code, just in case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/lista_recetas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="40dip"></ListView>
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="#000000"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#333333">
            <ExpandableListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ExpandableListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.